# Choosing AWS hosting for flutter website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

### Choosing AWS hosting for flutter website

- I have a flutter website and i have been thinking to host the site in
  AWS.
- I have saw the below features in aws which I can use for hosting
  my website.

### AWS Features available for Web Hosting

1. Using Amplify
2. s3 and cloudfront

I need to know what are the Pros and cons hosting flutter website with the above options so I can decide which one to use.

### My website is functionality:

- My website is build in Flutter Development Environtment with Dynamic
  Pages.
- It's an inventory management system mostly I get datas from multiple
  api's and process the data, then post the processed data using API
  call.
- it also have multiple pages and with mobile and desktop responsive
  designs.
- And also able to add my custom domain and have to add ssl certificate.

### Conlusion:

I don't have any idea which should I use to Host my website can anyone give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets First talk about Amplify**

Pros -

- Amplify provides an easy-to-use platform for deploying and managing web applications. It is designed to simplify the deployment process for developers.
- Amplify hosting comes with built-in HTTP authentication,
- Amplify supports serverless architecture, which means you don't need to manage servers. It automatically scales  on demand.
- Amplify integrates well with CI/CD pipelines, making it easy to continuously deploy updates to your site. Managed SSL Certificates: Amplify provides easy integration with AWS Certificate Manager to manage SSL certificates.

Cons -

- Usually expensive in comparative to s3+cloudfront

**Best for:** Static site generators, JavaScript based single page applications.

**Now s3 and Cloudfront**

Pros -

- Amazon S3 and CloudFront enable scalable and efficient content delivery, making it suitable for dynamic pages.
- ou have more control over your infrastructure settings, enabling better customization to your needs.
- Depending on your usage, S3 and CloudFront can be cost-effective, especially for high-traffic websites.
- You can easily integrate S3 and CloudFront with other AWS services for additional functionality.

Cons -

- Setting up S3 and CloudFront can be a steeper learning curve compared to Amplify, especially if you're new to AWS. You must manually configure and manage certain features of your hosting environment.
- Although it supports SSL, you may need to manually configure and manage SSL certificates than in Amplify.

**Best for:** Pre-packaged static sites provided by marketing organizations that are deployed via drag and drop

**Conclusion -**

Being a managed service and quick integrations makes amplify costlier. I see s3+cloudfront as cheaper, also. Also, web developers have been and prefer building static sites and storing data on S3 as it offers exceptional performance and can be easily scaled when the project grows.

Also there has been a word that "amplify internally uses s3+cloudfront".

[A quick summary over a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEAaz.png)